# how to validate button on server side and client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate my button first but i am wondering first should i validate from client side or server side? if client side validatetion then how and server side validation how?

```html
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnsave").click(function () {

                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addcustomer"/"customerdetail",
                    data: {
                        Name: $("#txtname").val(),
                        City: $("#txtcity").val(),
                        Address: $("#txtaddress").val()
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtname" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="city">City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcity" placeholder="Enter your City">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtaddress" placeholder="Enter your Address">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-default" id="btnsave">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
private SqlConnection con;
    // GET: addcustomer
   public ActionResult customerdetail()
   {
        return View();
   }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult customerdetail(customerdata obj)
   {
       custmerinfo(obj);

       return View();
   }


   private void connection()
   {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    }

   public void custmerinfo(customerdata obj)
   {
        connection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("addcustomer", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", obj.name);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", obj.city);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", obj.address);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Never trust user input. Always do server-side validation. Client-side validation is more responsive and reduces the number of invalid request.

Comment: You can start here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation. And since you are posting with AJAX you'll want to look up jQuery validation.

Comment: Validate what? You have not even bound your view to a model. I suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics of MVC. This is all handled out of the box (client and server side validation) by decorating your properties with validation attributes, bind to your model and posting it.

Answer (score 0):

you should validate form the client side and from the server side ,
cause when you validate from the client side it will make your website faster and more interactive and you won't get a not valid request from a normal user . 
so why you need to validate from the server side ? 
because any beginner programmer can submit a request to your server and if 
you wouldn't validate this request you would get a trouble in your web application.

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate serverside in any case. Clientside validation is a service to your user to make it clear to them what is needed and what not.

Since you're using MVC, you can use the build-in model validation to deal with a lot of the plumbing needed for validation. You didn't post your customerdata object (model), but you can add validation properties to the properties there to deal with validation.

Once that's up and running, serverside validation is as easy as adding a `ModelState.IsValid` in your `[HttpPost]` action. You'll need to do a little more work on the clientside -- the AJAX post action should not be allowed to start as long as your form is invalid.

Above all, I would recommend you read up on MVC model validation. You can find extensive explanations and examples here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: Thanks appreciate for your answer